Нужно научиться тестировать приложение в c++ Builder 11
Заканчиваю разработку приложения для надёжного удаления данных. Есть кнопки удалить файл и удалить папку. Для того, чтобы мою программу сертифицировали необходимо покрытие её тестами. Так вот, я не понимаю как это сделать, в интернете ничего найти не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать? С чего начать тестирование? Что почитать/посмотреть?
